# How to add "open with vscode" to context menu in manjaro?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, kde-plasma, manjaro

How to add "open with vscode" to context menu in manjaro ?

Hi there,

I install Code OSS on manjaro by Pacman,but i don't know how to add "open with vscode" to context menu,I already try dolphin extension,but when i click install,it show error,Please help me, Thanks!

BR

[Code OSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kko6e.png)

[dolphin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdK7N.png)

Comment: In the past you could simply Right-Click, choose properties, then choose the wrench icon to open the file associations. You can then look at the Opens With list of applications and chose Add, find VScode and add it to the list. You can move the position of VScode Up/Down in the list if you like. Save the settings and go back to flipper (dolphin). Now when you right click you should have VScode as an option in Open-With. Do it, check the box to set it as the desired default for that type file if you like. (this is from memory, so should get you close)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need the extension as in the recent version of dolphin 21.08 this setting exists

[image]